# Play store says my app is supported by 0 devices

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have recently finished building my first android app. I published it to the store today but it says it supports 0 devices. Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.guessthepicturespazam.guessit" >

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="נחש את המילה"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="נחש את המילה"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="נחש את המילה"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_store" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GameOverActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_game_over" >
        </activity>
    </application>
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true" />

</manifest>
```

This is my build.grade file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.GuessTheWordZahal.guessit"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'
}
```

I tried looking this problem up online but I couldn't find a problem similar to mine. Most apps have no supported devices because they use features that are only available in some or in no devices. I just can't figure out what's wrong in mine. I've actually tested this app on my samsung galaxy and it worked fine.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing the <uses-sdk> tag? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: These are already mentioned in my build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide supported sdkVersion

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="minimum(e.g "8")"
        android:targetSdkVersion="maximum(e.g "22")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Eclipse then mention your minSdkVersion & maxSdkVersion in your manifest file and if you are using Android Studio then mention these in build.gradle file.

**For Eclipse**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.guessthepicturespazam.guessit"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
 .......................
</manifest>
```

**For Android Studio**

edit your build.gradle file like as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.guessthepicturespazam.guessit"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Version name and Version code is important if you want to update your application in future.

Comment: Share your build.gradle file as well as your updated manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest is incorrect.

```
<supports-screens>
```

is currently placed in application tag but should be moved up, to manifest tag.
Check out manifest structure https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#filestruct

I suppose play-store parser couldn't find supports-screens information and decided that there is no screen supported. Please, correct manifest and let us know. Very interesting issue.

Comment: I moved the supports-screens tag up to the application tag, submitted the new apk as an update (so the old one was unpublished) and it still says it supports 0 devices..

Comment: did you move <supports-screens> up to head of xml? I mean order is matter